# SQL querying with DATES - not pulling correct data

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I'm running a simple query where I am trying to filter by a date, like this...

```
Select * from tblPurchasedProducts
WHERE  PurchasedOn >= '11/04/2016' AND PurchasedOn <= '11/08/2016'
```

But I am not able to see any results for 11/8/2016. I'm only able to see everything prior to 11/08/2016.

The date is saved in SQL SERVER as smalldatetime. I'm really not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Is the time an issue in this case.

I am required to save the PurchasedOn date with as datetime

EDIT:

@lamak
WHERE PurchasedOn  >= '20161104' AND PurchasedOn  <= '20161108'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be careful with your conditions. By using `<= '11/08/2016'` it's using the `00:00:00` time, that's why you are not getting results. Use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblPurchasedProducts
WHERE PurchasedOn >= '20161104' AND PurchasedOn < '20161109';
```

Comment: @Bobski try it again. It's the right answer, and _way_ better than the one you commented that worked for you.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn please see EDIT - this is my WHERE statement, with CAST I get 4 results. with this I only get 3 (omitting the one record on 11/8/2016)

Comment: @Bobski Are you using `< thanTheNextDay`?, I used `'20161109'`, not `'20161108'`

Comment: @joel sorry I didn't notice that he did 20161109 - No I am using TODAY as the latest day they can enter. If someones gonna search for something they won't be entering tomorrows date to look for todays records but rather todays.

Comment: @lamak yeah that's why it works. If i use in my original statement 11/9/2016 it works as well.

Comment: @Bobski Then use that date and add one day

Answer (score 0):

Dates in SQL are formatted YYYY MM DD, so you would write '2016/04/11'

Unless you override it but you will need to specify the date format.

Try:

```
    Select * from tblPurchasedProducts
    WHERE  PurchasedOn BETWEEN '2016-11-04' AND '2016-11-08'
```